# Confusing Pseudocode Example

Tags: java, pseudocode, insertion-sort

Trying to break down this simple pseudocode into java code

```
for j <- 2 to n
    do key <- A[j]
       i <- j - 1
    while i > 0 and A[i] > key
          do A[i+1] <- A[i]
             i <- i - 1
    A[i + 1] = key
```

It's just an insertion sort example, but I'm confused as to what the call for "do" without a while is after the first do while.

I have this so far:

```
for(int j = 2; j < arrayToSort.size(); j++)
    {
        int key, i;
        do
        {
            key = arrayToSort.get(j);
            i = j -1;
        }while(i > 0 && arrayToSort.get(i) > key);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you are confusing the `while` loop with `do-while`. The first `do` here is not a part of `while`. So, it's not a `do-while` loop.

It's just telling to do the shown assignment inside the `for` loop, before the `while` loop starts.

So, the equivalent code would be like:

```
for (int j = 2; j < n; ++j) {
    int key = A[j];
    int i = j - 1;

    while (i > 0 && A[i] > key) {
        A[i+1] = A[i];
        i = i - 1;  // can be replaced with '--i'
    }
    A[i + 1] = key
}
```

Comment: Oh so it's literally meant as a "do the following" not an actual do-while loop?

Comment: @kentoe Yes. Exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, definitely makes sense now. I haven't seen pseudocode using "do" that way

Comment: Had to wait a certain time to accept for some reason. Just did though! Thanks again

Comment: @kentoe Yeah you can only accept the answers after 15 minutes. You're welcome :)